# Best approach to program a PLC using dbc file? (CAN communication)

Tags: programming, can, plc, canopen

I'm pretty new using CAN Communication but I need to program a Phoenix Contact PLC in Structured Text. The PLC should communicate with a motor that uses CANOpen protocol. The only resource I have is the dbc file. I'm kinda lost about where to start. Unfortunately, Phoenix Contact only has a CAN library that is really limited to work with and the complete configuration is done via function blocks that represent the transparent CAN layer (you can't include EDS files or DBC files).

Should I use the messages ID's..? Decode every single combination we can possibly send/receive...?

If you have some suggestions/recommendations I would appreciate it.

Comment: Suggestions: http://www.plctalk.net/qanda/ and https://mrplc.com. Your question isn't really about electronics design so it's probably off-topic on this particular SE.